# Quit Terminal after Running SSH "shutdown" Apple (Shell) Script for Remote Machine

Tags: applescript, ssh, remote-control

I have made a small apple script (calling a shell script using ssh) to remotely shutdown/hibernate my windows machine. I export the script as application so I can easily call it from my raycast search.

```
set question to display dialog "Are you sure you want to hibernate pDesktop?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 1 with icon caution
set answer to button returned of question

if answer is equal to "Yes" then
    do shell script "ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'shutdown.exe /h'"
end if
```

This works fine, however after executing the script (or even just the shell ssh command in a terminal), the terminal on mac os hangs (because the remote server closes the connection) and I have to kill the process.

Is there any method to prevent this? Or a better/recommended method to remotely send a shutdown command?

Thanks
phil

Comment: Thanks for the info and sorry about this, I forgot to delete on the other site. Have done that now.

Comment: When using the `do shell script` _command_, in this use case, have a look at: [I want to start a background server process; how do I make do shell script not wait until the command completes?](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG5-I_WANT_TO_START_A_BACKGROUND_SERVER_PROCESS__HOW_DO_I_MAKE_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT_NOT_WAIT_UNTIL_THE_COMMAND_COMPLETES_) in the [Technical Note TN2065 `do shell script` in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the command on the other host with nohup and in background (&) :

```
"nohup ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'shutdown.exe /h’ &"
```

You may need to redirect output and error :

```
"nohup ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'shutdown.exe /h’ >./nohup.out 2>./nohup.err &"
```

Comment: that worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: hmmm it didn't work the second time I tried.

Comment: I added redirection of output and error

Comment: This asks me for quote?

`phil@Phil-MacBook:Scripts > nohup ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'shutdown.exe /h’ >./nohup.out 2>./nohup.err & `
then
`quote> `

Comment: I tried to write it like to did but on iPhone the ´ and " characters may not be the one you must use. Use simple quote for the woman’s executed by ssh and double quote for the whole string. You can try to execute the nohup ommand from a terminal window on MacOS.

Comment: I tried in the terminal but when using nohup with these options it would simply not do anything (i.e. remote machine was not suspended). After playing around a bit with the options I found psshutdown.exe tool, and I got it working with that, see my own answer.

Comment: Good if it works now

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested `nohup ... &` solution which did not work (it was asking for some input in the terminal and run as script it would still hangup). Then I tried the `nohup ... >./nohup.out 2>./nohup.err &` suggestion but simply nothing would happen.

So I played around with the different options trying to set countdown to hibernation to 1 second:

```
ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'shutdown.exe /h /t 1'
```

Unfortunately that did not work and I got an error message about `stdin not being a terminal`.

Because I did not only want to be able to hibernate my windows machine but also suspend it, I found the tool [psshutdown.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown). I had the same problems that the terminal or the apple script would hang when executing the command over ssh with:

```
ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'psshutdown.exe -h -t 0 -accepteula'
```

note: the option `-h` here is for hibernate.

After playing around with different options I eventually found how I can make it work without hangup:

```
ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'psshutdown.exe -h -t 1 -accepteula'
```

I simply changed the countdown from 0 seconds (`-t 0`) to 1 second (`-t 1`). I guess the extra second allowed the script to terminate before the remote machine would close the connection and make the script hang. This works for both hibernating and suspending the windows computer. For the latter you simply have to exchange `-h` for `-d`:

```
ssh -t phili@192.168.0.11 'psshutdown.exe -d -t 1 -accepteula'
```

Hope this helps anyone else trying to do the same.